# What is the defacto standard place for D libraries

Tags: d

I am looking for something like CTAN, CPAN, PyPI. A standard place for solid 3rd party libraries. There is Dsource but majority of the libraries seem to be defunct abandonware and dsource itself does not seem to have been updated since 2007.

Comment: Have you not seen the state of Phobos?  What makes you think there are any solid and mature 3rd party libraries.  You need to wait at least 2-3 years before anything interesting happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the closest thing to a central organized list of libraries right now is:

http://wiki.dlang.org/Libraries_and_Frameworks

There is also the dub repository:

http://code.dlang.org/

Answer (score 8):

DSource used to be the de facto standard place, but lately the trend seems to be to use Github.  Unfortunately the community is in the middle of the transition, so you probably have to search both places.

Comment: Is there a specific place in github I should be looking at, or is it spread out as several personal projects ?

Comment: Github fortunately has a view-by-language that let's you see all projects.  https://github.com/languages/D/most_watched

Also, D doesn't have a major community driven "best" library effort except in it's two "standard" libraries.  With 2.0, this is beginning to be centralised better, but I doubt it's something that can be predicted.

Answer (score 3):

2014 update for late comers:

The new package/library management tool is called "dub" and its repositories are here:

http://code.dlang.org/

Answer (score -1):

D libraries are spread all over the net ;)
dsource, github and ohloh are good places to start the search.